# Historical phrases with a modern viewpoint

Tags: frase

I recently read a post about "en territorio comanche". It put me wondering if some phrases are still used widely? If they are, whether they are still appropriate. I mean some may be better than others, some may be interesting given their historical and cultural significance and background. Others may be more controversial or even racist from a modern viewpoint.

I know "no hay moros en la Costa" exists as well as "el moro viejo nunca será buen cristiano".
In English, I am sure there are many such as,"to be put in a paddywagon" referencing the Irish "paddies" who were arrested for being drunk etc. in the 19th and 20th century in America. As an Irish person, I don't find it offensive because I am sure there were some disorderly people as well as well-behaved Irish people. A fact.
It is just interesting to think of such examples across the board. I would like to see examples and opinions.

Comment: Note that your assumption about the etymology of _paddy-wagon_ is far from certain. [Etymonline suggests](https://www.etymonline.com/word/paddy#etymonline_v_2978) it may come from the fact that apparently many policemen at the time were Irish, although I have found other sources with the same claim you mention. At the very least, it isn't clear.

Comment: Do you have a problem with punctuation? Are you on a mobile?

Comment: @terdon Yes, that is a distinct possibility.Definitely, in New York ,there were plenty of Irish in the police force.

Comment: @Lambie. No,I have no problem with punctuation. I use it regularly.Thanks for asking.

Comment: I will do my edit of the punctuation and spaces for you to see. By the way, I rejected the language edit. "put me wondering" was changed to "got me wondering", but I see no reason for that. :)

Comment: @Lambie I used a different device that I am not used to typing on which had a different keyboard. In Ireland we also use "it put me wondering"

Answer (score 5):

Seguro, en Castellano hay unas cuantas frases  de uso comun, cuya inercia  historico-cultural da cuenta del sesgo de racismos y prejuicios sociales extendidos (inconscientes) en el empleo cotidiano. Para ejemplificar, cito `Sure, there are a few of those compromised phrases in Spanish, reflecting the unconscious racial bias of cultural and historical roots. I may cite:`

> *Trabajar como (un) negro* 
> `To work like a black man (slave)`

La analogía no necesita mayor explicación, y se basa en la práctica histórica (por centurias) de la explotación de personas secuestradas de Africa, que las potencias coloniales emplearon como fuerza de trabajo en sus enclaves ultramarinos. `The analogy does not need much explanation. With its  quite straightforward meaning based off the historical exploitation of African slaves (during centuries) by European empires in their overseas colonies.`

Puede ser interesante listar además un término muy particular tambien, —no racista pero derivado de la cultura negra— my usado en Argentina coloquialmente para significar "problema" y/o (altísimo nivel de) "desorden" Forma parte del lunfardo rioplatense y del habla cotidiana, con un uso  extendido a otros paises sudamericanos como Uruguay, Chile, Paraguay, Colombia y Bolivia. Proviene de la palabra Angolesa "kilombo" (que significa [campamento de guerra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quilombo#External_links), donde los esclavos "cimarrones" —emancipados— se establecian) El tono de uso es, diría, jocoso, para referir a conflictos, situaciones complejas, muy desordenadas o salidas de control. `Another interesting one, used in some parts of south America (Argentina, Uruguay, Chile, Paraguay, Colombia and Bolivia ) in everyday conversation, to mean "brothel", and mainly "problem" and/or significantly out-of-proportion mess" . Though does not have direct racist connotations it comes from the Kimbundu word "kilombo" (war camp)[2]. In Argentina, I'd say, the term has a hilarious  —almost festive— tone, to humorously describe "problem", something quite "out of control" and "in a stage of severe disarray".`

La palabra `The word`

> [**Quilombo**](https://dle.rae.es/quilombo?m=form)

da pie a muchas expresiones de uso muy corriente relacionadas con problemas o desordenes extremos `forms rather common expressions related to conflict and problems in chaotic stages`:

> **Qué quilombo** (... es todo esto / se va a armar / se volvió nuestra vida / etc)

> `What a real mess` ... (*all this is / things are going to turn into / our life has became / etc*)

PD: En el [lunfardo porteño/rioplatense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunfardo) a "quilombo" se lo conoce como ***bolonqui*** (al revés)

`PS: In [the argot of Buenos Aires and Uruguay][3], the word "quilombo" may be put backwards, as "bolonqui"`

Comment: Right @mdeweyThank you for the warning,. I only translated in its raw meaning to seek absolute fairness . I felt like the use of an euphemism (to circunvent its harsh truth) would have lessen the awarrness of the original phrase's brutallity, (which is the main point of the question: what  phrases do keep a sediment of racism in our language and go unnoticed).

Comment: Si @terdon, oincidió el momento de ambos cambios. Ya lo puse como sugerías. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: You don't exactly provide the word, which by the way, is not an expression. ! Qué quilombo! [I saw a series about jail in Argentina and in the Spanish sub-titles, they spelled it like that.] But there's nothing really racist about it. It's also used in Colombia.

Comment: Corrected @Lambie, I added  the common expressions that word is included in